# Where are constructors stored in class file format

Tags: java, bytecode, .class-file

I have been looking into the java class file format.  I have specifically been looking into creating classes from byte-code.  I have been able to find most of the info that i need from the oracle documentation, and other Google searches.  However I haven't been able to find out how and where constructors are stored in the class file.  I thought they might be stored in the method table but i am not sure, and if they are i would like a specification of how they are stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JVM specification, section 2.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9):

> At the level of the Java Virtual Machine, every constructor written in the Java programming language (JLS §8.8) appears as an instance initialization method that has the special name `<init>`. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name `<init>` is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language.

Additionally:

> A class or interface has at most one class or interface initialization method and is initialized (§5.5) by invoking that method. The initialization method of a class or interface has the special name `<clinit>`, takes no arguments, and is void (§4.3.3).